# How to cleanly extract multi-page tables from PDFs?

Tags: r, tabulizer

I've been trying to use `tabulizer` to avoid hardcoding parsing that could possibly change with the next report. I was wondering if you all might have better ideas.

```
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)

who <- "https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200309-sitrep-49-covid-19.pdf"

page1 <- tabulizer::extract_tables(who, pages = 4, output = "data.frame") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  slice(5:n()) %>% 
  select(-`X.1`)

page2 <- tabulizer::extract_tables(who, pages = 5, output = "data.frame") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rbind(colnames(.))

page3 <- tabulizer::extract_tables(who, pages = 6, output = "data.frame") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rbind(colnames(.))

colnames(page2) <- colnames(page1)
colnames(page3) <- colnames(page1)

dat <- page1 %>% rbind(page2) %>% rbind(page3)
```

If you run this you'll notice the region and totals need to be removed but the page split and tall rows are where I'm having trouble.

Comment: In my experience, I had to parse each page separately and then `rbind` the results. It required removing repeated column headers (and other page miscellany). I don't know of any robust way to "know" that a table on page `i` is perfectly continued by a very-similarly-looking table on page `i+1` in a rendered PDF.

Comment: (Then again, I shifted from `tabulizer::` to `pdftools::pdf_text` for some reason I cannot recall at the moment.)

Comment: Decided it was just easier to parse it with Abode Pro.